# SwiftUI ForEach 'identified(by:)' is deprecated. Use ForEach(_:id:) or List(_:id:)

Tags: swiftui

On XCode 11 beta 4 the following seems to be deprecated and I don't know how to rewrite this. Does anybody know how to use `ForEach(_:id:)`?

```
@State private var showTargets = [
    (id: 1, state: false, x: 109.28, y: 109.28),
    (id: 2, state: false, x: 683, y: 109.28),
    (id: 3, state: false, x: 1256.72, y: 109.28)
]
```

...

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {

        ForEach(showTargets.identified(by: \.id)) { item in
            Text(String(item.x))

        }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

***(Still working with Xcode 11.0 / Swift 5.1)***

I haven't downloaded Xcode Beta 4 yet, but according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/3364100-init), it should be something like:

```swift
ForEach(showTargets, id: \.id) { item in
    Text(String(item.x))
}
```

You can also use a `struct` that conforms to `Identifiable` (note that this won't work on tuple because you can't add protocol conformance):

```swift
struct Targets: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var state: Bool
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
}

let showTargets = [
    Targets(id: 1, state: false, x: 109.28, y: 109.28),
    Targets(id: 2, state: false, x: 683, y: 109.28),
    Targets(id: 3, state: false, x: 1256.72, y: 109.28)
]

ForEach(showTargets) { item in
    Text(String(item.x))
}
```

Comment: For some reason when I try to change the Text inside the ForEach into a more complex View I get Type '_' has no member 'id'. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Hard to tell without the code, but it might be an error inside the `ForEach` statement. SwiftUI is not always very explicit when it comes to error messages.

Comment: I don't know actually, it might be better to open a new question, to keep this one clean.

Answer (score 2):

Adding example for list

```
List(showTargets, id: \.id) { item in
     ItemRow(item: item)
 }
```

when showTargets conforms to identifiable protocol:

```
List(showTargets) { item in
     ItemRow(item: item)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list objects conform to the identifiable protocol & do have id (uniquely defined) variable inside along with other properties of an object.

**You can simply iterate over the list by not passing the id: parameters.**

```
List(showTargets) { item in
 Text(String(item.x))
}
```

**Otherwise, You can simply iterate using ForEach:**

```
List(showTargets, id: \.id) { item in
 Text(String(item.x))
}
```

Checkout Few Reference Doc:
[Identifiable Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/identifiable)

Comment: The second snippet doesn't use `ForEach`