# .identified(by:) Deprecated?

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

This code was previously working in Xcode11 Beta 4. In the latest Beta 5 I'm getting an error on the ".identified(by:)" block of code.

I looked through the release notes on XCode11 Beta 5 but I didn't see any reference to .identified(by:) being deprecated.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct Popups: Decodable {
    let name, truckRating, upcomingLocation, cuisine, truckImage, region, 
city, state, currentLocation, numberOfRatings, truckExpense : String
}

class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<NetworkManager, Never>()

    var popups = [Popups]() {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    init() {
        guard let url = URL(string:
            "https://www.example.com/db.json") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in

            guard let data = data else { return }

            let popups = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Popups].self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.popups = popups
            }


            print("Completed fetching JSON")
        }.resume()
    }
}        

struct ItemsView: View {

        @State var networkManager = NetworkManager()

        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                List (
                    networkManager.popups.identified(by: \.name)
                ) { popup in
                    ItemsRowView(popup: popup)
                }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Pop Ups"))
            }
        }
    }
```

The error message states "Value of type '[Popups]' has no member 'identified'"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SwiftUI ForEach 'identified(by:)' is deprecated. Use ForEach(\_:id:) or List(\_:id:)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57109557/swiftui-foreach-identifiedby-is-deprecated-use-foreach-id-or-list-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.identified(by:)` is deprecated. As you correctly stated, this is not noted in the release notes for Xcode beta, but in the release notes for iOS beta, which is why you couldn't find it. It's a little confusing because the changes relating to SwiftUI are scattered across the release notes for iOS 13 beta, Xcode 11 beta, and macOS Catalina beta.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_ipados_13_beta_5_release_notes

> The identified(by:) method on the Collection protocol is deprecated in
>   favor of dedicated init(*:id:selection:rowContent:) and
>   init(*:id:content:) initializers. (52976883, 52029393)

But the `identified(by:)` deprecation happened in beta 4, so the following also applies:

> SwiftUI APIs deprecated in previous betas are now removed. (52587863)

This question is sort of a duplicate of [SwiftUI ForEach 'identified(by:)' is deprecated. Use ForEach(_:id:) or List(_:id:)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57109557/swiftui-foreach-identifiedby-is-deprecated-use-foreach-id-or-list-id?noredirect=1&lq=1), but the confusion around where the deprecation is mentioned in the release notes merits keeping it as a separate question.